# Create windows XP's live USB using ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

My hard disk crashed.. I can run Ubuntu using a pendrive by making a live USB of Ubuntu, which I made using Windows 7.
In the similar way, I want to run Windows XP too using another pen drive (without hard disk) and I want to make it from Ubuntu (12.04).
The resources I have are Ubuntu's live USB, Windows XP and Windows 7 installation disk, some blank DVDs but no hard drive.
I have very basic knowledge of Linux.
Thanks

Comment: XP from USB is not an official supported deployment method.  While it is "possible" most solutions that actually do it are for the purposes of piracy.  Voting to close as too localised.

Comment: Installing another OS can not really be done from Ubuntu anyway.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/16958-ubuntu-and-winusb-a-simple-tool-that-enable-you-to-create-your-own-usb-stick-windows-installer-from-an-iso-image-or-a-real-dvd

**WinUSB** is a simple tool that enable you to create your own usb stick windows installer from an iso image or a real DVD.
This package contains two programs:
- WinUSB-gui: a graphical interface which is very easy to use.
- winusb: the command line tool.

Supported images: Windows Vista, Seven+ installer for any language and any version (home, pro...) and Windows PE.

**Install WinUSB in ubuntu**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: WinUSB not working for XP, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried various approaches to this in the past, and in the end, there are a few possible ways you *can* do it, but nothing that is guaranteed to work.

For me, the easiest method is to install [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) which includes a copy of a "windows live" version with it.

Another method would be to create a BartPE install using a VirtualBox Windows VM.

With your given resources, you might install your Windows 7 copy in a VM, and use something like [WinBuilder](http://www.instantfundas.com/2010/12/how-to-create-windows-7-live-cddvdusb.html) to create a legal live version of Windows 7. You can then boot into a live Windows 7 version from your USB.

For Windows XP, you can use the similar [BartPE tool](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) to build a live Windows XP install.